# Permission problems when installing MATLAB R2013b

Tags: 13.10, permissions, software-installation, matlab

I am trying to install MATLAB and I am running into some issues with the installer program with Ubuntu 13.10.

I get to the screen which tells me to select the directory I wish to install in, I then select next and it tells me the folder does not exist and asks me if I wish to create a new one; if  I select to create the folder it gives me the error:

```
Failed to create folder (/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/)
```

I then tried to create the folder manually; using `sudo mkdir /usr/local/MATLAB/` and then `sudo mkdir /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/`, but the installation continues to fail with the same error.

Has anyone encountered and overcome this error before?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you run the MATLAB installer with root privileges?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I'm not sure, I ran it through the GUI rather than through terminal, so perhaps not?

Comment: Try to run the installer via terminal with `sudo`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I can no longer find the installer; do you happen to know where it's usually stored after being downloaded?

Comment: Error: Cannot locate Java Runtime Environment (JRE).
The directory /home/heru/matlab/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

Try to run the MATLAB installer via terminal using root privileges aka `sudo`.

- Go into the MATLAB directory via terminal.
- Change `install` file into an executable one by running

  `sudo chmod +x install`
- Now run the installer ,

  `sudo ./install`

Comment: Still it shows /tmp/mathworks_2704/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: Permission denied

Comment: if you had any problem with matlab then ask it as a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting Java problem while installing MATLAB that means you extracted MATLAB. I recommend you mount the .iso file in Archive Manager then browse to mount place and run

```
sudo ./install
```

This way you won't have this problem.